# Problem with escaping parameterised arguments

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I feel *really* reluctant to ask this question as it feels like I must be missing something really obvious. However, I am unable to find existing questions with exactly the same problem.

We have a script that we should not edit, and it is causing a problem in how it is handling arguments that include whitespace. I have reduced the problem to a very simple reproducible case:

First, I created a simple script that just outputs the commandline arguments passed to it:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i; do
    echo $i
done
```

Then I define an environment variable that will be passed into the commandline

```
MYOPT="With Space"
```

Then, and this is the part I am unable to change in our environment, I call the command using the variable as a parameter. Unfortunately, the variable is not quoted in our environment.

```
./mycommand.sh $MYOPT
```

The output of this is, as you would expect,

```
./mycommand.sh $MYOPT
"With
Space"
```

If you do quote the variable in the above command, it works. This seems to be the generally accepted solution to this problem when looking around at other similar questions.

```
./mycommand.sh "$MYOPT"
"With Space"
```

However, as I mentioned, we are unable to change how this script is called.

I tried adding in extra quotes in the environment variable as follows, but this too did not help:

```
MYOPT="\"With Space\""
./mycommand.sh $MYOPT
"With
Space"
```

Is there a way of defining this environment variable with spaces such that it can be passed into a script without quoting it in the invocation?

For those who are interested, this problem is presenting itself in our RHEL7 tomcat environment. JAVA_OPTS is set in tomcat.conf and we have -Dparamaters="with spaces". The main control script that comes with Tomcat does not quote these JAVA_OPTS when it calls Java, which leads to this problem. I reduced the problem to the simple example above.

Comment: That's POSIX word splitting (`zsh` doesn't do it). Can you fiddle with `IFS` without breaking anything? Otherwise, the code that can't be changed must be corrected to use double quotes.

Comment: Try `printf -v MYOPT  '%q' "With Space"`

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  The double quotes are stripped out of the variable assignment and do not appear in the output.  Perhaps you have Unicode double quote characters in the original?

Comment: Also see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943) for the Right Way to Do It.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** go back from `./mycommand.sh $MYOPT` to the value of `MYOPT`. That's why you didn't find a way to do it: it's impossible. `mycommand.sh` does not receive enough information to reconstruct the original value.

For example, if the value of `MYOPT` is `*` then `mycommand.sh` is called with the list of file names in the current directory. It has no way to know how this list was constructed.

**If you know that the value of `MYOPT` follows certain rules** then you may be able to reconstruct it. The simple version of these rules is:

- The value doesn't contain any of the characters `\[*?` or tab or newline.
- The value does not start or end with a space and does not contain consecutive spaces.

Under these assumptions, `"$*"` in `mycommand.sh` will give you the value of `MYOPT`. But keep in mind that this cannot work in general.

The proper solution is to fix your environment. In the shell language, `$MYOPT` does not mean “take the value of `MYOPT`”, it means “take the value of `MYOPT`, split it according to the value of `IFS`, and treat each resulting part as a wildcard pattern which is expanded if it matches at least one file”. The way to write “take the value of `MYOPT`” is `"$MYOPT"`, or more generally to use `$MYOPT` [inside double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Comment: Gilles, what about using `printf -v MYOPT '%q' "With Space"` to shell-quote `MYOPT`, is that a viable option?

Comment: @iruvar It sets the variable `MYOPT` to a form that can be parsed with `eval`. That's useful sometimes, but not here: if you have control over the caller to make it do that, change the caller to quote `$MYOPT`.